# Meteorjs collection insert in loop gives wrong results without errors

Tags: meteor

I have an array of data that I want to fill some collection with. I have this collection as SomeCollection.

If I go through array like this

```
_.each(dataArray, function(d) {
 var retId = SomeCollection.insert(d); 
 console.warn(retId);
});
```

Where dataArray has 720 unique items with unique _id's.

On loop execution I get all retIds returned and no errors.

If I write SomeCollection.count() after that, I get 720.

If I reload page after that, SomeCollection.count() gives some number less than 720 (each reload the same number, but number different after 'filling' script re-execution), it can be 320, 521, etc.

I do it on client with an 'admin' user who have whole SomeCollection published and subscribed.

Collection is clean before this loop; I remove all item from it explicitly.

Why is it happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was I just reloaded page too fast. After loop ended, insertion process seems to be still active.